# Issue with updating one to one model in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, class, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Tables are

User Table:

```
 id
 name
 email
 etc.
```

Profile Table:

```
 user_id
 role
 address
 city
 state
 etc.
```

On tinker i did:

```
 $user = App\User::with('profile')->find(3);
```

Output is:

```
 App\User {#756
 id: 3,
 name: "Alejandra Kerluke Jr.",
 email: "balistreri.laurel@example.com",
 deleted_at: null,
 created_at: "2016-06-23 05:12:03",
 updated_at: "2016-06-29 11:05:45",
 Profile: App\Profile {#768
   user_id: 3,
   role: "",
   address: """
     50111 Wendy Row Apt. 732\n
     Kingburgh, OR 42164-7189
     """,
   city: "Manteland",
   state: "Vermont",
   country: "Belgium",
   phone: "1-226-766-4182 x5574",
   fax: "1-507-985-3523 x708",
   zip: 48446,
   status: 0,
   deleted_at: null,
   created_at: "2016-06-23 05:12:03",
   updated_at: "2016-06-23 05:12:03",
 },
```

}

Then i did:

```
>>> $user->name="YYYYYY"
>>> $user->email='abc@example.com'
>>> $user->profile->role = 'XXXXX'
>>> $user->push();
```

This throws the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `profiles` set `role` = inspector, `updated_at` = 2016-06-29 11:29:30 where `id` is null)'
```

I don't know what's wrong with this piece of code.  I am new to Laravel and any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think profile should be use like this `$user->profile()->role = 'XXXXX'`

Comment: I tried but still same error

Comment: You need to provide the `id` of the user to update profile relationship. Like `$user->id=3`

Comment: if i have data in variable $user why do i need to assign it again?

Comment: You must add an `id` column in the profile table because eloquent will assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`.

Comment: there is no `id` of profile in data that you have shown get that id also or define proper relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @AmitKumar you can either add column id in profile table or you can provide proper relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$user = App\User::with('profile')->get()->find(3);
```